# Android Studio import project (Folder Structure)

Tags: android, import, structure, directory, project

Hi Stackoverflow Community,

I have get one Android App Project. It was made with Android Studios. But now I have a problem after importing that project. After importing I can not launch the Application. The "Error Box" shows the following:

```
Error:(5, 0) Cause: startup failed:

build file 'C:\Users\Test\Desktop\v2\src\build.gradle': 5: unexpected     char: 0xBC @ line 5, column 24.
v2AppKey {
^
1 error
```

Also I see that the folder Structure is diffrent. I can not understand why. I have attached two Pictures. Picture one is the folder Structure of the Project I get and Picture number two is the project I have created.

Thanks
Mr_X!

Picture 1(Project I get from someone)
http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150217/o52themo.jpg

Picture 2(My Project folder structure)
http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150217/xqtnw6ix.jpg

Comment: How did you import ? by selecting the whole folder or by selecting gridle.build file?

Comment: By selecting the "Project folder"

Comment: You should select the gridle.build file to import the project!

Comment: Sorry You should select build.gridle file file->importproject->your folder->build.gridle

Comment: Yes, but I can not run this project. I think because the Folder Structure I can not launch. Look at the two pictures that I had attached.

Comment: Your folder Structure looks fine. what error do you get?

Comment: Why are they diffrent? Folder structure 1 and 2?

Comment: if you have a new copy of the project delete this and import them again by selecting the build.gridle file

Comment: did you able to fix it?

Comment: No ^^ It doesn't function. Also there come an Error that path to git is not executable. But I don't use Git